# is there a /c/ vs. /k/ or /g/ vs /ɟ/ minimal pair in turkish

Tags: phonemes, turkish

i checked the wiki subarticle ["Consonants"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_phonology#Consonants) and there is an example of /kar/ vs /ca:r/ ([youglish link](https://youglish.com/pronounce/k%C3%A2r%20etmek/turkish?), as evidence for ":") which might not be a good minimal pair. do you know one? /g/ vs /ɟ/ would also work for me.

":" ruins it for me, because I consideer vowel length contrastive. "Karanın kası" means "the muscle of the land", but if I pronounce it as /ka:sı/, it sounds as if someone is dictating the letter k, giving "land" as an example word with initial k.

Comment: What is your argument against *kar* vs. *kâr"? This goes to your theory of "minimal pair".

Comment: Does Turkish have contrastive vowel length? I didn't think it did.

Comment: @user6726 kâr has a longer a.

Comment: @Draconis I can't find a resource but I can think of an example of contrastive vowel length (a loanword from Arabic).

Comment: @cottn, this is an important factual claim that should be in the question. Comments can be deleted without a trace, and the question itself should contain all of the relevant facts.

Comment: @user6726 ok thanks I updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this web page](https://sozluk.gov.tr/) as an informant, the example [kar] "snow" vs. [car] "profit" is a minimal pair. The only phonetic difference in the words is initial consonant: the vowels are not different in length (performances by the same speaker). In the context __C{#,C}, a long vowel is regularly shortened. It is true that the underlying forms differ w.r.t vowel length, but "minimal pair" is a property of phonetic forms, not underlying forms. Another example is [kap] "container, [cap] "ankles" (glosses are guesswork since that webpage is in Turkish). If you search *kâ* on the page it gives you all *kâ*-initial words (*kâm* *retains* a long vowel, surprisingly, which is useful for calibrating judgement of vowel length in the [car/kar] example).